# How to secure microservice REST API with zuul API gateway

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, spring-security-oauth2, netflix-zuul

I am learning microservice and following microservice architecture of my project as:

```
UI/angular<-->API Gateway/zuul proxy<-->Service Registry/Eureka<-->multiple microservices(few are dependent, few public accessable, few authenticated)
```

I need to secure the services in a centralized place(At the time of logging and for each request). I searched for it some are saying to provide security check in each service or in api gateway. But what about direct access to service, how security will be checked.

```
Required JWT with oAuth.
```

So please guideme with hint,code snippet,or links

I have checked few links but no proper clarity which one to follow for better purpose.
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-oauth-jwt

https://www.xoriant.com/blog/product-engineering/microservices-security-using-jwt-authentication-gateway.html

Also how ensure authentication if a service is calling another service using feign client

Comment: https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi__router_and_filter_zuul.html

Comment: Thanks can you provide code link as this link is about routing...I need jwt + oAuth